# preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, preg-grep

I have a mySQL query to fetch data from a whole year: `$allYearData = $stmt->fetchAll();`
Now i´d like to split this array into 12 parts, separated by month.

**UPDATE**
So i count rows in `$allYearData`:

```
//Count all keys
$allYearDataCount = Count($allYearData);
```

Now i use PHP `preg_grep()` to search and put result in new array `$janData`.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $allYearDataCount; $i++){
    $janData[] = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $allYearData[$i]);
}
```

Result:
 `preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given`

If i check `$allYearData` for data i can see it´s full.

```
$allYearData = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($allYearData);
```

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 7811 [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3105 [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1 [element_nr] => 3105 [vart] => B.Avf [vem] => Blå [anteckn] => [datum] => 2015-09-29 18:00:19 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 7812 [objekt_element] => 23050-121-1_3107 [objekt_nr] => 23050-121-1 [element_nr] => 3107 [vart] => B.Avf [vem] => Blå [anteckn] => [datum] => 2015-09-29 18:00:22 ) [2....`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `$allYearData = $stmt->fetchAll();` before iterating over `$allYearData` using the `for` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $allYearData; $i++){
    $janData[] = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $allYearData[$i]);
}
```

First, you have $i <= $allYearData, so allYearData is number, or array? With loop there should be an integer there. Use count($allYearData) instead. and not <= but <.

Second, use foreach loop, so you will have no problem with counting items. Or think twice before using for.

Comment: I updated my question with `count`. Also i removed `=`. Now the loop runs smoothly. Thank you. I will also have a look at `foreach`. Now i have a new problem. `$janData` contains same values as `allYearData` .. The filter loop don´t work...

Comment: - is a special char inside regexp, so instead of /^2015-01-.*$/, try to use: /^2015\-01\-.*$/

Answer (score 1):

You have to change

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $allYearData; $i++){
```

to

```
for($i = 0; $i < $allYearData; $i++){
```

because your array starts at index `0` and will end with index `count($allYearData)-1`.

In your code you are accessing the array with an index out of bounds so that `$allYearData[$i]` will be `null` in the last iteration of your `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

In this Code `$allYearData[$i]` must be array. If you will have a look for error `preg_grep() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given` that 2 parameter needed and you have given but last parameter is not array and its required so its assume `null` last parameter. You will have to check your loop and make sure second parameter is `Array` data type

```
for($i = 0; $i < $allYearData; $i++){
    $janData[] = preg_grep("/^2015-01-.*$/", $allYearData[$i]);
}
```